# How to fix the Reporting Services that hangs?

Tags: sql-server-2016

This is related to SQL Server 2016 SP1's Reporting Services. The Reporting Services was working as expected but suddenly the Web Service URL and the Web Portal URL both hang. The information from Microsoft is inadequate as it does not tell how to fix it.
Summary of Observations:

Microsoft Edge (latest): Authentication is prompted and takes 3 attempts (same username\password) to go to the URL. The page hangs and does not load.

Microsoft Internet Explorer: Does not prompt but directly go to the Web Service URL and Web Portal URL loading the pages.

Chrome (latest): No prompting for authetication, immediately loads the web urls

Report Builder: Can connect to Report Server and reports on the server can be edited on the report builder.

The suggested browser is Microsoft Edge and it is having a problem.

The Dell Laptop is running Windows 10 Pro (build 16299.19, Version 1709).
This question is also on SQL Server Reporting Services forum on MSDN. More details are on my blog:
[https://hodentekmsss.blogspot.com/2017/10/this-is-serious-security-breach-problem.html](http://This%20is%20related%20to%20SQL%20Server%202016%20SP1's%20Reporting%20Services.%20The%20Reporting%20Services%20was%20working%20as%20expected%20but%20suddenly%20the%20Web%20Service%20URL%20and%20the%20Web%20Portal%20URL%20both%20hang.%20The%20information%20from%20Microsoft%20is%20inadequate%20as%20it%20does%20not%20tell%20how%20to%20fix%20it.%20Summary%20of%20Observations:%20Microsoft%20Edge%20(latest):%20Authentication%20is%20prompted%20and%20takes%203%20attempts%20(same%20username%5Cpassword)%20to%20go%20to%20the%20URL.%20The%20page%20hangs%20and%20does%20not%20load.%20Microsoft%20Internet%20Explorer:%20Does%20not%20prompt%20but%20directly%20go%20to%20the%20Web%20Service%20URL%20and%20Web%20Portal%20URL%20loading%20the%20pages.%20Chrome%20(latest):%20No%20prompting%20for%20authetication,%20immediately%20loads%20the%20web%20urls%20Report%20Builder:%20Can%20connect%20to%20Report%20Server%20and%20reports%20on%20the%20server%20can%20be%20edited%20on%20the%20report%20builder.%20The%20suggested%20browser%20is%20Microsoft%20Edge%20and%20it%20is%20having%20a%20problem.%20The%20Dell%20Laptop%20is%20running%20Windows%2010%20Pro%20(build%2016299.19,%20Version%201709).%20This%20question%20is%20also%20on%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services%20forum%20on%20MSDN.%20More%20details%20are%20on%20my%20blog:%20https://hodentekmsss.blogspot.com/2017/10/this-is-serious-security-breach-problem.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check the proxy setting in microsoft edge. besides stop and restart the services in Reporting Services Configuration Manager

Comment: Thanks. The laptop is on Wi-Fi and proxy setting is automatic. Stopping/starting RS server from RS Configuration Manager as well as from Control Panel does not help.